# Swift 4 AVcapturesession not calling captureOutput Delegate

Tags: ios, video, swift4.1

So im trying to create class that handles a video output stream for my app and the delegate method "captureoutput" is never getting called.

I set up my input devices and configured the outputs but I cannot get the delegate with the output info to get called. I've looked at other suggestions and tried everything I have read, but I'm really stumped.

I'm using Xcode 9 and swift 4

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol FrameExtractorDelegate: class {
func captured(image: UIImage)
}

class FrameExtractor: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

private let position = AVCaptureDevice.Position.front
private let quality = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

private var permissionGranted = false
private let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "session queue")
private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
private let context = CIContext()

weak var delegate: FrameExtractorDelegate?

override init() {
    super.init()
    checkPermission()
    sessionQueue.async { [unowned self] in

        self.captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        self.configureSession()
        self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        self.captureSession.startRunning()

    }
}

// MARK: AVSession configuration
private func checkPermission() {
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) {
    case .authorized:
        permissionGranted = true
    case .notDetermined:
        requestPermission()
    default:
        permissionGranted = false
    }
}

private func requestPermission() {
    sessionQueue.suspend()
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { [unowned self] granted in
        self.permissionGranted = granted
        self.sessionQueue.resume()
    }
}

private func configureSession() {
    guard permissionGranted else { return }
    captureSession.sessionPreset = quality
    guard let captureDevice = selectCaptureDevice() else { return }
    guard let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }
    guard captureSession.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput) else { return }
    captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer"))
    guard captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else { return }
    captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    guard let connection = videoOutput.connection(with: AVFoundation.AVMediaType.video) else { return }
    guard connection.isVideoOrientationSupported else { return }
    guard connection.isVideoMirroringSupported else { return }
    connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
    connection.isVideoMirrored = position == .front
}

private func selectCaptureDevice() -> AVCaptureDevice? {
    return AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.front).devices.first
}

// MARK: Sample buffer to UIImage conversion
private func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return nil }
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}

// MARK: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
 func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    print("output captured")
    guard let uiImage = imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        self.delegate?.captured(image: uiImage)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: its the second line of the init is the check permissions.... when I step through, all the lines of configure session get ran (no early returns) and permission has been granted so thats why im stuck

Comment: after more investigation after the session gets initialized, like it should but and it drops frames until class finishes viewdidload and then it seems something is getting deallocated so it doesn't get called anymore